# How does one show that $(n-2)! = 2^{m-1} m! (n - 2m)!$ has only one solution for $n\ne 6$?

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

The obvious solution is 1, for $n=6$ there is another one - $m=3$. How does one show that for other $n$ there are no solutions but $m=1$?

This is to show that for $n\ne 6$ all automorphisms of $S_n$ are inner.

Thank you.

Comment: Should $2^m$ be $2^{m-1}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n=2$, then $m=0$ is a solution.  On the other hand, $m=0$ is not a solution for any larger $n$, and I suppose we want $1\le m\le n/2$.

Rewrite the equation to be solved as
$$
\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-2m)!(2m-2)!}=\frac{2^{m-1}m!}{(2m-2)!}
$$
which is equivalent, when $m>1$, to
$$
\binom{n-2}{2m-2}=\frac{m}{(2m-3)!!}.
$$
The left side is an integer for all valid $m$, but the right side is an integer only for $m=2$, $3$.  We can rule out $m=2$ since then we must have $\binom{n-2}{2}=2$ which has no solution.  Hence the only possible solution is $m=3$ which necessitates that $\binom{n-2}{4}=1$ or $n=6$.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you!